# iOS Different result about calculating text size between boundingRectWithSize and CoreText method

Tags: ios

Same single line of text get different width between `boundingRectWithSize and`CoreText` method.

Here is my code and results:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSeletor:(id)sender {
    [self getSeparatedLinesWithText:self.contentField.text fontSize:self.fontField.text.floatValue labelWidth:10000];
}

- (void)getSeparatedLinesWithText:(NSString *)text fontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize labelWidth:(CGFloat)labelWidth
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize];
    CTFontRef myFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)([font fontName]), [font pointSize], NULL);
    NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
    CTParagraphStyleSetting set[kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierCount] = { 0 };
    int count = 0;
    CTLineBreakMode paraLineBreak = (CTLineBreakMode)NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    set[count].spec = kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineBreakMode;
    set[count].valueSize = sizeof(CTLineBreakMode);
    set[count].value = &paraLineBreak;
    count++;
    CTParagraphStyleRef style = CTParagraphStyleCreate(set, count);

    [attStr addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)myFont range:NSMakeRange(0, attStr.length)];
    [attStr addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName value:(__bridge id)style range:NSMakeRange(0, attStr.length)];
    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attStr);
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0,0,labelWidth,100000));
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
    NSArray *lines = (__bridge NSArray *)CTFrameGetLines(frame);

    CGFloat width = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName :font} context:nil].size.width;
    CTLineRef obj = (__bridge CTLineRef)(lines[0]);
    CGRect r = CTLineGetBoundsWithOptions(obj, kCTLineBoundsExcludeTypographicLeading);
    NSLog(@"\ntext %@\nboundingRectWithSize %f\nCoreText %f\nboundingRectWithSize/CoreText %f",text,width,r.size.width,width/r.size.width);
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Design sketch:

[image: Design sketch]

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: When text is long, only three lines are displayed.Use CoreText get three lines of content is not the same length to just three lines length on UILabel

Comment: and what are you using to display text ? I mean uilabel ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display maximum three lines in label then you not need to calculate width etc. You can manage it from your interface (storyboard or xib) by autolayout.

give your label have three constraint like : `leading,trailing,top` and set number of line to `3` ! if you have fixed width label then set constraints like : `top,leading, fixed width` and number of line should be three!

and it will resize according to content and will not show more than three lines!

Comment: When text lines are more than 3,I also need to Intercept part of the third line end and append ...show all

Comment: "...show" is a UIButton, so I need to know the width of the third line.

Comment: you should take look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

Comment: Thanks! But I have to support iOS 7